# No se sube una foto al servidor local con PHP usando la cámara

Tags: php, html

Tengo un pequeño problema con mi aplicación para navegador, la cual está alojada en un servidor local con XAMPP.

Tengo un formulario en el que hay `inputs` de texto y uno de archivo.

A la hora de subir el archivo/imagen, desde mi ordenador, se sube correctamente y cuando lo hago con mi dispositivo android, buscando y seleccionando una imagen de la galería, también se sube. Pero resulta que si en vez de elegir el archivo en la galería hago una foto directamente, ésta no se sube correctamente.

Dejo el código aquí abajo:

```
<?php 

 require_once 'conexion.php';
  $result;

  $connn = dbConnect();
  // Create the query
  $user ="";
   $sqll = 'SELECT * FROM ******* ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
  $result = $connn->query($sqll);
  $rows = $result->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $idImg = $row['id'];
}
    $target_path = "img/";
    $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];
    $tipo_archivo = explode("/", $tipo_archivo);
    $tipo_archivo= '.'.$tipo_archivo[1];
    $nombre_archivo= $idImg.$tipo_archivo;
    $target_path = $target_path.$nombre_archivo;

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            window.location='index.php';
            </script>";
    } 
     else{
        echo $target_path;
    }
 ?>
```

**Aquí el `input`**

```
<form method="post" action="insertar.php" id="carga_archivo" name="carga_archivo" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <!--inputs...-->
    <p><span>Imagen: </span><input type="file" id="file-input" name="uploadedfile"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="pill orange" style="border:none;width: 100%;">
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías definir mejor a qué te refieres con que "no se sube correctamente"? ¿Significa que se sube pero que el archivo está mal?

Comment: En el input, el archivo aparece como subido, pero al enviar el formulario, no sube el archivo a la carpeta definida. Sólo se sube si selecciono el archivo desde la galeria

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que se envía con un tipo diferente que rompe la forma en la que creas el nombre de archivo. ¿Podrías hacer un `file_put_contents('depuracion.log', json_encode($_FILES, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));` al principio de tu archivo para depurar qué se está enviando cuando lo haces desde la cámara? Comparte el contenido de `depuracion.log` cuando hagas la prueba. Gracias.

Comment: Problablemente desde la camara la imagen se codifica en base64, si se sube desde un fichero, tendria una ruta de acceso pero si es desde la cam, problablemente solo te devuelva un imagen en base64

Comment: @JorgeBowen, gracias por participar. Un `<input type="file" ... />` sube un archivo codificado tal y como se indica en el `enctype="multipart/form-data"` del formulario. Lo que es probable es que cambie el índice `'type'` u otro valor que no espera.

Comment: @OscarGarcia que tenga enctype no quiere decir que sea una imagen base64, porque al final recoges la ruta fisica del archivo en tmp $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']

Comment: Lo que no se es como tu camara devuelve la imagen, si la guarda en un directorio tmp que en ese caso funcionaria al igual que si eliges una ruta de un archivo, pero si la cam devuelve la imagen codificada y no la ruta, a lo mejor el problema viene alli, podrias poner una captura de lo que envia el navegador al enviar una imagen desde la camara¿?

Comment: Hola @Tefef . Ya que no he obtenido respuesta a las preguntas que te planteé te redacto una respuesta con los dos principales problemas que veo en tu código. Es decir, no controlar cuándo el índice `type` no está definido y no comprobar si la subida se completó correctamente. Si tienes alguna duda o sigue sin funcionar házmelo saber.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En tu código veo principalmente dos problemas que pueden ser el origen de que el archivo no se esté guardando correctamente. El primero está relacionado con la ausencia de comprobación del estado de la subida y el segundo está relacionado con la forma en la que obtienes la extensión del archivo.

#### Comprobando la subida

Antes de trabajar con el archivo subido debes comprobar si hubo algún tipo de error durante la subida. Todos los [mensajes de error están en esta página del manual de PHP](http://php.net/features.file-upload.errors).

Aquí te muestro una forma de gestionar cualquier eventualidad durante el proceso de subida:

```
<?php
/* Comprobamos si hubo algún error */
if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  /* Mostramos un mensaje de error personalizado en cada caso */
  switch ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']) {
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
      die('El tamaño de archivo excedió el máximo definido en upload_max_filesize');
      break;
    default:
      /* Para no extenderme capturo el resto de mensajes aquí */
      die('Hubo un error inesperado durante la subida del archivo');
  }
}
```

En caso de que el problema sea que estás enviando un archivo más grande (`UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`) del valor predeterminado o configurado en [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.upload-max-filesize), puedes cambiar su valor en el `php.ini` por, por ejemplo, 32 MiB:

```
upload_max_filesize 32M
```

#### Obtención de la extensión del archivo

Otro problema que puedes sufrir es que el navegador no esté enviando el índice `type` con el valor esperado o correcto.

Deberías corregir tu código para detectar la extensión del archivo de maneras alternativas en caso de estar vacío dicho índice:

```
<?php
/* Asumimos que ya se ha comprobado la existencia del índice del archivo */
$tipo_archivo = explode("/", $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type']);
if (count($tipo_archivo) !== 2) {
    /* Forzamos la extensión */
    $tipo_archivo = 'jpg';
} else {
    /* Usamos el que recibimos en el tipo MIME */
    $tipo_archivo = $tipo_archivo[1];
}
```

También podrías hacer uso de [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/function.finfo-file) para obtener el contenido real del archivo, independientemente de la información que nos proporcione el navegador:

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$tipo_archivo = explode(
  "/",
  finfo_file(
    $finfo,
    $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']
  )
);
/* Si falló la detección forzamos la extensión */
if (count($tipo_archivo) !== 2) {
  $tipo_archivo = 'jpg';
} else {
  $tipo_archivo = $tipo_archivo[1];
}
```

O bien usando la interfaz OOP:

```
<?php
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$tipo_archivo = explode(
  "/",
  $finfo->file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])
);
/* Si falló la detección forzamos la extensión */
if (count($tipo_archivo) !== 2) {
  $tipo_archivo = 'jpg';
} else {
  $tipo_archivo = $tipo_archivo[1];
}
```